# What does "activity?." mean in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity

I am trying to use a code snippet from the official android documentation (https://developer.android.com/training/printing/photos#kotlin) which is the doPhotoPrint() function in the code that I have attached, in order to learn how to use the PrintHelper class in Kotlin and Android Studio. See the attached image of the the code snippet:

[image: doPhotoPrint() function]

The problem is that when I put the code in Main Activity in my test app, it keeps showing "activity?." as red. Why is this the case and how can I get the code to work so that is provides the user with the option to print? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you linked is just a general *how to use a library function* snippet - it's not put in any context, but we can assume it's probably written with a `Fragment` in mind. Fragments have a [`getActivity()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#getActivity()) method that returns the `Activity` it's currently attached to (or *null* if it's not)

Kotlin allows you to access getter and setter functions from Java code [as if they were properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#getters-and-setters) - so basically, instead of having to do `value = getThing()`
and `setThing(newValue)` you can treat it like a variable: `value = thing`, `thing = newValue` etc. So when you access the `activity` property in this code, it's really calling `getActivity()`. And because the result can be null, you use the `?` to null-check it before trying to do anything with it.

Really what that snippet is saying is, this code needs access to a `Context`, and it's using an `Activity` as one in the example. If you have a `Fragment`, you can just drop this code right in. If you're in an `Activity` though, then you obviously don't need to *get* one - `this` is your Activity! And you don't need to null-check it either of course. (And there's no `activity` property or `getActivity()` method to access, which is why it's showing up red and unrecognised)

So you can just replace that stuff and the checking code around it with:

```
private fun doPhotoPrint() {
    // using 'this' to pass the current activity as the context
    val printHelper = PrintHelper(this).apply {
        scaleMode = PrintHelper.SCALE_MODE_FIT
    }
    val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.droids)
    printHelper.printBitmap("droids.jpg - test print", bitmap)
}
```

Comment: Much appreciated, your explanation was perfect and made a lot of sense. It never occurred to me that the snippet was based an app using fragments.

Answer (score 1):

It is showing red because you have not declared the nullable object activity anyway before you use it

Comment: And he probably doesn't need to-  this is an activity class he's implementing it in.  He can just drop the activity?. and access the function directly.  He doesn't need to worry about being null because this can never be null

Comment: just remove activity wrapper and in context use this instead